# Как сделать авторизацию по имени в .net core 2.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

делаю чат и параллельно учу .net core 2.1. и signalR. Извиняюсь если вопрос задан некорректно, но как сделать простейшую авторизацию по имени в .net core 2.1?

Comment: Ну... запростите логин пароль `TextBox`-ами (само проще).

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте загуглил вопрос "авторизация .net  core". Первые 5 ссылок дают более чем полную информацию. Так же когда вы создаете проект сервака, так есть уже реализация авторизации. Во многих примерах просят используют email. Сделайте то же самое, только по имени